# Break react component code into two js file

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Current I am minify my `index.js` using webpack and after minifying it is having size more than 1MB. When I am trying to divide the code between two file it wont work. Is it possible to get requirement done

**index.js**

```
import statement here
```

**index1.js**

```
render method here
```